# accessing id from name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
class SubjectTeachersController < ApplicationController

def new
  @st = SubjectTeacher.new   
  @tnames = Teacher.pluck(:tname)
  @subs = Subject.pluck(:sub_name)

end    

def create
   @tech = Teacher.find(params[:tname]).id
   @sub = Subject.find(params[:sub_name]).id
   @st = SubjectTeacher.create(:teacher_id => @tech, :subject_id => @sub )
    if @st.save
        flash[:notice] = " creates successfully"
    else
      render('new')
        end    
  end   
end
```

I created mamy to many relationship between Subject & Teacher. SubjectTeacher is join table of Subject & Teacher. In SubjectTeacherController.

here, @tnames stores all the teacher name while @subs stores all subjects name. I want to access the id of both in controller...HOW?
 Is any changes shall I do in create function? plz tel me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails provides 'magic' finder methods, of the form `Model.find_by_attribute`.

In this case, we can use `Teacher.find_by_tname(params[:tname])` and `Subject.find_by_sub_name(params[:subname])`